# How to use data posted for one view into another view in django rest

Tags: django, file, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project in which user enters some ranges like (starting_date, ending_date, starting_roll_num, ending_roll_num, and subject) and it queries the DB and returns a csv file
but i want to add another feature which enables the user to also get the remaining data after he has entered the ranges and downloaded the first file but for this I have to make an other function, the problem is how will I use the data posted on the first function.
Here is my code:

serializer.py

```
class DatasetGeneratorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_roll = serializers.IntegerField()
    end_roll = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField()
    end_date = serializers.DateField()
    subject = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def attendance_datasetgenerator(request):
    serializer = DatasetGeneratorSerializer(request.data)
    start_roll = serializer.data['start_roll']
    end_roll = serializer.data['end_roll']
    start_date = serializer.data['start_date']
    end_date = serializer.data['end_date']
    subject = serializer.data['subject']

    att= Attendance.objects.filter(date__range=(start_date,end_date), student__pk__range=(start_roll,end_roll), subject__exact=subject)
    df1 = DataFrame(att.values())
    path = 'attendance_dataset.csv'
    csv1 = df1.to_csv('attendance_dataset.csv')
    response = HttpResponse(csv1, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file1.csv'
    return response
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking but just call the other function from that function or make a new route and call it after the first API call.

Comment: I mean I have 2 functions one to view the file and the other one to download the file, the file depends on the data posted by the front end, so my question is when the user post a data how can i use the same data in both the functions